# Read USB RFID with a Raspberry & python

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, rfid, hid

I'm trying to read an USB RFID device with python.
The divce works in HID mode and I can find it as /dev/hidraw0
I have a tag which code is '210054232F' (I can see the code printed on the shell scanning it with the RFID)

So I try to open the device with a python script and capture the code read but I'm stuck...

This is the python code:

```
import sys

fp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb')

while True:
   buffer = fp.read(16)
   for c in buffer:
       if ord(c) > 0:
           print c
   print "\n"
```

This is the output (with a lot of square and unorintable characters in the middle):
[image]
If I print the code with:

```
for c in buffer:
       if ord(c) > 0:
           print ord(c)
```

This is the output:

1
31
1

1
30
1

1
39
1

1
39
1

1
34
1

1
33
1

1
31
1

1
32
1

1
31
1

1
2
9
1

1
40
1

I can't find any kind of pattern to decode the data.

Have you any suggestions or other way to solve the issue?

Thanks,
Federico

Comment: Hi Federico
If you have solved it, 
Can you please share solution for this problem,
as I am facing the same.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the data with different types, so as `int`, `char` or even as a `list`. Your problem is that the presented data is not of the type, as you print it. This makes the strange symbols.

Comment: Hi itzFlubby, thank you for your answer. I solved in a better and cleaner way using python-evdev library handling input events from the reader. Thanks, Federico.

Answer (score 0):

The reader behaves as a USB keyboard, so you need to assemble the value from USB keyboard scan codes.

```
import sys
import struct
    
def read_tag(f):
    vle = 0
    while True:
        b = f.read(1)
        c = b[0]
        if c >= 30 and c <= 39:
            vle = vle*10 + (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)[c-30]
        elif c == 40: # Enter key
            # little to big endian conversion and return 
            vbe = struct.unpack("<I", struct.pack(">I", vle))[0]
            return vbe
            
def main():            
    fp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb')
    while True:
        tag = read_tag(fp)
        print(f"{tag}, {hex(tag)[2:]}")        
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```